# Flowplayer for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, video, streaming

I want to use Flowplayer in Ubuntu server.  How can I do this?  I searched a lot in Google but didn't get any thing related with Flowplayer on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Flowplayer (assuming you are talking about the software from http://flowplayer.org/) is just some JavaScript and Flash.

If you are running an Ununtu based webserver, then you upload the flash and js files as you would with any other static file.

If you are running a web browser on an Ubuntu desktop, then you just need to install the [Flash plugin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Flash) for whatever browser you are using (and you should have asked this on Superuser).